# No results when trying to populate array in a function

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use a function to populate an array with computer names to pass on to another part of a script.  I am pinging all computer names in an OU and when it comes back as online, I would like to add it to an array.  However, whenever I run the function, it comes back with no computer names at all.

If I step through the function by hand, it works fine.  Here is the code:

```
Function Return-OnlinePCsInOU {

[cmdletbinding()]

param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$OU
    )

$computers = @()
$machines = (Get-AdComputer -SearchBase $OU -Filter *).name

$machines | Foreach {

If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -Quiet) {
$computers += $_

}
}
}
```

Running this function doesn't populate the array.

So stepping through, this gives me all of the computer names in the OU:

```
$machines = (Get-AdComputer -SearchBase $OU -Filter *).name
```

Running this piece gets the online machines and populates the array no problem:

```
$machines | Foreach {

If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -Quiet) {
$computers += $_

}
}

PS C:\> $computers
71832
72098
83547
77437
77216
83427
81276
73293
71754
81308
67332
71765
```

I am hoping this is something stupid on my part, but I cannot figure out why it won't work the way I am hoping.  Any help would be great!

Thanks,
Drew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope of both `$computers` and `$machines` is limited to the function `Return-OnlinePCsInOu`. When the function exits, they are no longer in scope. Also your function produces no output, so nothing is "returned". When you run the commands direct in the shell/ISE, the variables are in scope of the current session and you are able to use them.

You can watch this by adding some simple output:

```
Function Return-OnlinePCsInOU {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String] $OU)

    $computers = @()
    $machines = (Get-AdComputer -SearchBase $OU -Filter *).name
    "Found: $machines" # writes search results
    $machines | Foreach {
        If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -Quiet) {
            "Pinged $_" # writes when ping works
            $computers += $_
        }
    }
}

Return-OnlinePCsInOU
$computers # no output
$machines # no output
```

As you don't use the variables `$computer` or `$machine` for anything besides building the arrays, I would skip using them all together.  The function can produce the desired output directly and you can collect it in a variable.

```
Function Return-OnlinePCsInOU {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String] $OU)

    Get-AdComputer -SearchBase $OU -Filter * |
        Foreach {
            If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.Name -Count 1 -Quiet) {
                $_.Name
            }
    }

}

# Scope is outside function, collect the output here.
$onlineComputers =  Return-OnlinePCsInOU 'DC=example,DC=org'
```

Comment: +1 for this answer.  However, why tag `cmdletbinding()`?  Or is that just habit?  Not a critique, just that I can't see what requires it at first glance, and I often include it myself even if I don't intend to use its expanded features.

Comment: @Colyn1337 It was in the OP's code and I just copied/pasted into an editor to start writing my answer. :)

Comment: Beautiful sir, thank you for your help.  @Colyn1337 Yes, the cmdletbinding() is a force of habit  :)